# How to get only the last part of a path in Python?

Tags: python, path, path-manipulation

In [python](/questions/tagged/python), suppose I have a path like this:

```
/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/
```

How can I get just the `folderD` part?

Comment: path.split('/')[len(path.split('/'))-1:][0]

Answer (score 617, accepted):

Use [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to strip off any trailing slashes, then [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) gives you the last part of the path:

```
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.normpath('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/'))
'folderD'
```

Using only `basename` gives everything after the last slash, which in this case is `''`.

Comment: I initially thought `rstrip('/')` would be simpler but then quickly realised I'd have to use `rstrip(os.path.sep)`, so obviously the use of `normpath` is justified.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Windows long paths, e.g., `'\\\\?\\D:\\A\\B\\C\\'` and `'\\\\?\\UNC\\svr\\B\\C\\'` (returns an empty string)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384788/5659969) solution works for all cases.

Comment: @jinnlao's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54868730/9835872) is much much better nowadays.

Comment: I'd add `str.strip` around it, too, because based on input, you might have whitespaces, but that might just be me

Answer (score 129):

With python 3 you can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module ([`pathlib.PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths) for example):

```
>>> import pathlib

>>> path = pathlib.PurePath('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/')
>>> path.name
'folderD'
```

If you want the last folder name where a file is located:

```
>>> path = pathlib.PurePath('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/file.py')
>>> path.parent.name
'folderD'
```

Comment: well, just to point it out `PurePath` vs `Path`, the first provides "purely computational operations" (no I/O), while the other ("concrete path") inherits from the first but also provides I/O operations.

Comment: @Paolo To expand on this, this answer applies to non-pure paths as well

Answer (score 39):

You could do

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD')
```

**UPDATE1:** This approach works in case you give it /folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/xx.py. This gives xx.py as the basename. Which is not what you want I guess. So you could do this -

```
>>> import os
>>> path = "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD"
>>> if os.path.isdir(path):
        dirname = os.path.basename(path)
```

**UPDATE2:** As lars pointed out, making changes so as to accomodate trailing '/'.

```
>>> from os.path import normpath, basename
>>> basename(normpath('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/'))
'folderD'
```

Comment: In Python-think, os.path.basename(".../") correctly yields ''.  Yes, I, too, find that sub-optimal.  The ...basename(...normpath... solution below is canonical, though.

Comment: @lars yeah! just saw that in that case normalize the path first before feeding it to basename. os.path.basename(os.path.normpath('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/'))

Comment: UPDATE2 is the best approach I have found so far.

Comment: thumbs up for the UPDATE2

Answer (score 27):

Here is my approach:

```python
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.basename(
        os.path.dirname('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/test.py'))
folderD
>>> print os.path.basename(
        os.path.dirname('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/'))
folderD
>>> print os.path.basename(
        os.path.dirname('/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD'))
folderC
```

Comment: What does your approach solve different/better than the aforementioned?

Comment: @user1767754: though terse, this does illustrate a solution that works with our without a file name, while also showing the pitfall if a final directory does not have a trailing `/` (and without needing purepath)

Answer (score 11):

I was searching for a solution to get the last foldername where the file is located, I just used `split` two times, to get the right part. It's not the question but google transfered me here.

```
pathname = "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/filename.py"
head, tail = os.path.split(os.path.split(pathname)[0])
print(head + "   "  + tail)
```

Comment: You can also use `os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(pathname))` which would give `folderD` in your example. See answer from @Mike Miterer

Answer (score 9):

If you use the native python package **pathlib** it's really simple.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> your_path = Path("/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/")
>>> your_path.stem
'folderD'
```

Suppose you have the path to a file in folderD.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> your_path = Path("/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/file.txt")
>>> your_path.name
'file.txt'
>>> your_path.parent.name
'folderD'
```

Comment: In your 2nd example `stem` will only return `file` not `file.txt`. If you want `file.txt` you need `your_path.name`. [Pathlib Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)

Comment: Should be your_path.parent.name that gives "folderD"

Comment: Actually, it was the result which was wrong since it was meant as an example of what the output would look like, but for clarity's sake, I like your suggestion better.

Answer (score 8):

I like the [parts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) method of Path for this:

```
grandparent_directory, parent_directory, filename = Path(export_filename).parts[-3:]
log.info(f'{t: <30}: {num_rows: >7} Rows exported to {grandparent_directory}/{parent_directory}/{filename}')
```

Comment: My favorite, even cleaner: `'/'.join(Path(export_filename).parts[-3:])`

Answer (score 0):

During my current projects, I'm often passing rear parts of a path to a function and therefore use the `Path` module. To get the n-th part in reverse order, I'm using:

```
from typing import Union
from pathlib import Path

def get_single_subpath_part(base_dir: Union[Path, str], n:int) -> str:
    if n ==0:
        return Path(base_dir).name
    for _ in range(n):
        base_dir = Path(base_dir).parent
    return getattr(base_dir, "name")

path= "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/"

# for getting the last part:
print(get_single_subpath_part(path, 0))
# yields "folderD"

# for the second last
print(get_single_subpath_part(path, 1))
#yields "folderC"
```

Furthermore, to pass the n-th part in reverse order of a path containing the remaining path, I use:

```
from typing import Union
from pathlib import Path

def get_n_last_subparts_path(base_dir: Union[Path, str], n:int) -> Path:
    return Path(*Path(base_dir).parts[-n-1:])

path= "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/"

# for getting the last part:
print(get_n_last_subparts_path(path, 0))
# yields a `Path` object of "folderD"

# for second last and last part together 
print(get_n_last_subparts_path(path, 1))
# yields a `Path` object of "folderc/folderD"
```

Note that this function returns a `Path`object which can easily be converted to a string (e.g. `str(path)`)

Answer (score -4):

```
path = "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/"
last = path.split('/').pop()
```

Comment: Seriously, use the `os.path` module.

Comment: Do people try their answers before posting?

Answer (score -7):

```
str = "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/"
print str.split("/")[-2]
```

Comment: he wants `folderD`. not `folderC`

Comment: It gives "folderD" because the trailing slash makes the final item in the list be ""

Comment: Seriously, use the `os.path` module.