# Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format

Tags: python, path

Which Python library can I use to extract filenames from paths, no matter what the operating system or path format could be?

For example, I'd like all of these paths to return me `c`:

```
a/b/c/
a/b/c
\a\b\c
\a\b\c\
a\b\c
a/b/../../a/b/c/
a/b/../../a/b/c
```

Comment: This question is crazy. There is no `reliable` way to parse a path with forward and backward slashes on all operating systems. On Unix you CAN have a backslash in a folder name. You can only implement something that will work "most of the time", aka bug. Better find a way to avoid such crazy paths. Use system libraries for parsing paths, but also for building paths to begin with. The best solution to this problem is to eliminate such ambiguous paths. Good Luck!

Comment: As an example of what @Roland said: `\a\b\c` is a valid filename on Linux. Returning just `c` instead may be invalid and dangerous.

Answer (score 1060, accepted):

Using `os.path.split` or `os.path.basename` as others suggest won't work in all cases: if you're running the script on Linux and attempt to process a classic windows-style path, it will fail.

Windows paths can use either backslash or forward slash as path separator. Therefore, the `ntpath` module (which is equivalent to os.path when running on windows) will work for all<sup>(1)</sup> paths on all platforms.

```
import ntpath
ntpath.basename("a/b/c")
```

Of course, if the file ends with a slash, the basename will be empty, so make your own function to deal with it:

```
def path_leaf(path):
    head, tail = ntpath.split(path)
    return tail or ntpath.basename(head)
```

Verification:

```
>>> paths = ['a/b/c/', 'a/b/c', '\\a\\b\\c', '\\a\\b\\c\\', 'a\\b\\c', 
...     'a/b/../../a/b/c/', 'a/b/../../a/b/c']
>>> [path_leaf(path) for path in paths]
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

<sup>(1) There's one caveat: Linux filenames *may contain backslashes*. So on linux, `r'a/b\c'` always refers to the file `b\c` in the `a` folder, while on Windows, it always refers to the `c` file in the `b` subfolder of the `a` folder. So when both forward and backward slashes are used in a path, you *need* to know the associated platform to be able to interpret it correctly. In practice it's usually safe to assume it's a windows path since backslashes are seldom used in Linux filenames, but keep this in mind when you code so you don't create accidental security holes.</sup>

Comment: on Windows, `os.path` just loads the `ntpath` module internally. Using this module, it is possible to handle the `'\\'` path separators even on Linux machines. For Linux the `posixpath` module (resp. `os.path`) will simplify the path operations to allow only posix style `'/'` separators.

Comment: @moooeeeep So we could use Stranac's answer, and it is reliable? (**"Using os.path.split or os.path.basename as others suggest won't work in all cases: if you're running the script on Linux and attempt to process a classic windows-style path, it will fail"** -- the quote is from Lauritz's post -- and I don't understand, does this warning concerns Stranac's answer, or not).

Comment: @johnc.j. Only when you need to parse Windows style paths (e.g., `r'C:\path\to\file.txt'`) on a Linux machine, you need to use the ntpath module. Otherwise, you can use the functions from os.path. This is because Linux systems normally allow the use of the backslash characters in filenames (as explained in the answer).

Comment: Isn't your solution equivalent to `os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))` ?

Comment: For what it's worth to future visitors to this question, I ran into the situation Lauritz was warning about and his solution was the only one that worked. No finangling with os could output just the filename. So imho, ntpath is the way to go.

Comment: Why would you use a Windows-style path on Linux? Aren't those invalid on Linux, meaning that you are probably doing something wrong if you're doing that?

Comment: Failed case:
import ntpath
print(ntpath.basename("C:\a\b\s\d\f_a\aasdas_o_g.json"))
Results: d_aasdas_o_g.json

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I have to process Windows-style paths on Linux when processing data from Windows systems (like event logs) on a Linux system.  This is probably much more common than you think, especially in the security world.

Answer (score 1891):

There's a [function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) that returns exactly what you want

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(your_path))
```

*WARNING: When `os.path.basename()` is used on a POSIX system to get the base name from a Windows-styled path (e.g. `"C:\\my\\file.txt"`), the entire path will be returned.*

*Example below from interactive python shell running on a Linux host:*

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16)
[GCC 9.3.0] on Linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> filepath = "C:\\my\\path\\to\\file.txt" # A Windows style file path.
>>> os.path.basename(filepath)
'C:\\my\\path\\to\\file.txt'
```

Comment: If you want to process paths in OS independent way, then for os.path.basename(u"C:\\temp\\bla.txt") you are expecting to get 'bla.txt' . The question is not about obtaining a valid filename, but extracting the name for a path.

Comment: On my Google search for finding the filename of a path, this answer was the most helpful.  My use case is only on Windows anyway.

Comment: `os.path.basename(your_path)` This worked! I wanted script path: `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` and script name: `os.path.basename(os.path.realpath(__file__))`. Thanks!

Comment: @AdiRoiban Could you please elaborate your comment? I tested it on Windows 7 and I actually get "bla.txt'. Simply saying, I don't see any problem (for myself).

Comment: @johnc.j. The point is, when you attempted this on Linux, you'd get `'C:\\temp\\bla.txt'` instead.

Comment: Note, this doesn't work on all the cases listed by OP. If the `your_path` ends in a `/`, then `os.path.basename(your_path)` returns `''`. To get around this, you need to remove any trailing path separators first.

Comment: @stranac You're right, that's awfully egocentric of the Linux implementation, to not consider backslashes in the path as proper pathing separators. On the bright side, Windows-style paths _do_ work on Linux, but you have to use ___forward slashes only___ (so you could do `filepath.replace('\\', '/')` to get some plat-independence here)

Comment: @bobobobo The Linux implementation is the only correct way to implement this functionality. The issue here is that POSIX paths and Windows paths are incompatible and can't be processed without knowing the OS to which they belong. It's impossible to disambiguate the path `a\b.txt` which is a valid single component path on Linux *but also* a valid double component path on windows. What you're criticizing here is impossible to solve with paths alone.

Comment: @AdiRoiban "process paths in OS independent way" - this is just not possible. On Linux I can create a file with filename `r'c:\temp\bla.txt'`, so returning `bla.txt` on Linux would be just invalid.

Answer (score 390):

[os.path.split](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)
is the function you are looking for

```
head, tail = os.path.split("/tmp/d/a.dat")

>>> print(tail)
a.dat
>>> print(head)
/tmp/d
```

Comment: Just for other users to be careful, this returns "" if the paths ends in "/" or "\"

Comment: When I try  "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\button\button.py" it returns thi  "ProjectShadow*utton*tton"   for everything other than this it return correct result

Comment: @amitnair92 - Either do this: r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\button\button.py" or this: "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\ProjectShadow\\button\\button.py" - "\b" is a  special character (system 'bell' I think), similar to how \r or \n signify newline/carriage return. Prefixing the string with r"C:\..." means use the given raw input

Answer (score 324):

In python 3.4 or later, with **`pathlib.Path`**:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path    
>>> Path("/tmp/d/a.dat").name
'a.dat'
```

The `.name` property will give the full name of the final child element in the path, regardless of whether it is a file or a folder.

Comment: 3.4 to 3.6 or later, depending exactly which pathlib items you use.

Comment: can also use Path("some/path/to/file.dat").stem to get the filename without the file extension

Comment: ...and `pathlib.Path('some/path/to/file.dat').suffix` yields the extension.

Answer (score 89):

```
import os
head, tail = os.path.split('path/to/file.exe')
```

tail is what you want, the filename.

See [python os module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) for detail

Comment: Just for other users to be careful, this returns "" if the paths ends in "/" or "\"

Answer (score 43):

```py
import os
file_location = '/srv/volume1/data/eds/eds_report.csv'
file_name = os.path.basename(file_location )  #eds_report.csv
location = os.path.dirname(file_location )    #/srv/volume1/data/eds
```

Comment: As sweet and concise as an answer can get! Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

My personal favourite is:

```
filename = fullname.split(os.sep)[-1]
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to get the filename automatically you can do

```
import glob

for f in glob.glob('/your/path/*'):
    print(os.path.split(f)[-1])
```

Answer (score 15):

In your example you will also need to strip slash from right the right side to return `c`:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = 'a/b/c/'
>>> path = path.rstrip(os.sep) # strip the slash from the right side
>>> os.path.basename(path)
'c'
```

Second level:

```
>>> os.path.filename(os.path.dirname(path))
'b'
```

update: I think `lazyr` has provided the right answer. My code will not work with windows-like paths on unix systems and vice versus with unix-like paths on windows system.

Comment: Your answer won't work for `r"a\b\c"` on linux, nor for `"a/b/c"` on windows.

Comment: of course, `os.path.basename(path)` will only work if `os.path.isfile(path)` is `True`. Therefore `path = 'a/b/c/'` is not a valid filename at all...

Comment: @fmaas os.path.basename is purely a string-processing function. It does not care if the file exists or whether it's a file or dir. `os.path.basename("a/b/c/")` returns `""` because of the trailing slash.

Comment: `lazyr` you are right! I didn't thought about that. Would it be safe to just do `path = path.replace('\\', '/')` ?

Comment: @Skirmantas I suppose, but it doesn't feel right. I think path processing should be done with the built-in tools that were made for the job. There's [a lot more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4580931/566644) to paths than meets the eye.

Comment: indeed, I think lazyr has the most powerful function ;)

Answer (score 15):

```
fname = str("C:\Windows\paint.exe").split('\\')[-1:][0]
```

this will return : **paint.exe**

> change the sep value of the split function regarding your path or OS.

Comment: This is the answer I liked, but why not just do the following?
```fname = str(path).split('/')[-1]```

Answer (score 12):

**File name with extension**

```
filepath = './dir/subdir/filename.ext'
basename = os.path.basename(filepath)
print(basename)
# filename.ext

print(type(basename))
# <class 'str'>
```

**File name without extension**

```
basename_without_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))[0]
print(basename_without_ext)
# filename
```

Answer (score 11):

This is working for linux and windows as well with standard library

```
paths = ['a/b/c/', 'a/b/c', '\\a\\b\\c', '\\a\\b\\c\\', 'a\\b\\c',
         'a/b/../../a/b/c/', 'a/b/../../a/b/c']

def path_leaf(path):
    return path.strip('/').strip('\\').split('/')[-1].split('\\')[-1]

[path_leaf(path) for path in paths]
```

Results:

```
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 11):

It’s work!

```py
os.path.basename(name)
```

But you can’t get file name in Linux with Windows file path. Windows too.
os.path load different module on different operator system :

- Linux - posixpath
- Windows - npath

So you can use os.path get correct result always

Comment: Please make sure that your solution was not already proposed in another answers like the [top one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384838/6682517). Also there are some caveats that described in these top questions and their comments.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a regex-only solution, which seems to work with any OS path on any OS.

No other module is needed, and no preprocessing is needed either :

```
import re

def extract_basename(path):
  """Extracts basename of a given path. Should Work with any OS Path on any OS"""
  basename = re.search(r'[^\\/]+(?=[\\/]?$)', path)
  if basename:
    return basename.group(0)


paths = ['a/b/c/', 'a/b/c', '\\a\\b\\c', '\\a\\b\\c\\', 'a\\b\\c',
         'a/b/../../a/b/c/', 'a/b/../../a/b/c']

print([extract_basename(path) for path in paths])
# ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']


extra_paths = ['C:\\', 'alone', '/a/space in filename', 'C:\\multi\nline']

print([extract_basename(path) for path in extra_paths])
# ['C:', 'alone', 'space in filename', 'multi\nline']
```

Update:

If you only want a *potential* filename, if present (i.e., `/a/b/` is a dir and so is `c:\windows\`), change the regex to: `r'[^\\/]+(?![\\/])$'` . For the "regex challenged," this changes the positive forward lookahead for *some sort of slash* to a negative forward lookahead, causing pathnames that end with said *slash* to return nothing instead of the last sub-directory in the pathname. Of course there is no guarantee that the *potential* filename actually refers to a file and for that `os.path.is_dir()` or `os.path.is_file()` would need to be employed.

This will match as follows:

```
/a/b/c/             # nothing, pathname ends with the dir 'c'
c:\windows\         # nothing, pathname ends with the dir 'windows'
c:hello.txt         # matches potential filename 'hello.txt'
~it_s_me/.bashrc    # matches potential filename '.bashrc'
c:\windows\system32 # matches potential filename 'system32', except
                    # that is obviously a dir. os.path.is_dir()
                    # should be used to tell us for sure
```

The regex can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/PEALFz/2).

Comment: you are using re, why not os module ?

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel it's been a long time. If I remember correctly, regex is used as a cross platform solution in this case. You can process windows file names on a Linux server, for example.

Answer (score 10):

If your file path not ended with "/" and directories separated by "/" then use the following code. As we know generally path doesn't end with "/".

```
import os
path_str = "/var/www/index.html"
print(os.path.basename(path_str))
```

But in some cases like URLs end with "/" then use the following code

```
import os
path_str = "/home/some_str/last_str/"
split_path = path_str.rsplit("/",1)
print(os.path.basename(split_path[0]))
```

but when your path sperated by "\" which you generally find in windows paths then you can use the following codes

```
import os
path_str = "c:\\var\www\index.html"
print(os.path.basename(path_str))

import os
path_str = "c:\\home\some_str\last_str\\"
split_path = path_str.rsplit("\\",1)
print(os.path.basename(split_path[0]))
```

You can combine both into one function by check OS type and return the result.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe just my all in one solution without important some new(regard the tempfile for creating temporary files :D )

```
import tempfile
abc = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='/tmp/')
abc.name
abc.name.replace("/", " ").split()[-1]
```

Getting the values of `abc.name` will be a string like this: `'/tmp/tmpks5oksk7'`
So I can replace the `/` with a space `.replace("/", " ")` and then call `split()`. That will return a list and I get the
last element of the list with `[-1]`

No need to get any module imported.

Comment: What if the filename or a directory contains a space ?

Comment: What about a direct split("/")[-1] ?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a number of files in a directory and want to store those file names into a list. Use the below code.

```
import os as os
import glob as glob
path = 'mypath'
file_list= []
for file in glob.glob(path):
    data_file_list = os.path.basename(file)
    file_list.append(data_file_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen double-backslashed paths, are they existing? The built-in feature of python module `os` fails for those. All others work, also the caveat given by you with `os.path.normpath()`:

```
paths = ['a/b/c/', 'a/b/c', '\\a\\b\\c', '\\a\\b\\c\\', 'a\\b\\c', 
...     'a/b/../../a/b/c/', 'a/b/../../a/b/c', 'a/./b/c', 'a\b/c']
for path in paths:
    os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(path))
```

Comment: Those are not double backslahes. They are single backslashes, and they need to be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os

path = r"C:\py_auto_script\testing.xlsx"
os.path.basename(path)
=> 'testing.xlsx'

os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(path))
=>'C:\\py_auto_script'
```

Comment: Please, do not provide code only answer ,provide the explanation as well. Moreover, I fail to see how your answer adds something mor ethan the 22 already existing answer on this 11 years old question.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows separator can be in a Unix filename or Windows Path.  The Unix separator can only exist in the Unix path.  The presence of a Unix separator indicates a non-Windows path.

The following will strip (cut trailing separator) by the OS specific separator, then split and return the rightmost value.   It's ugly, but simple based on the assumption above.   If the assumption is incorrect, please update and I will update this response to match the more accurate conditions.

```
a.rstrip("\\\\" if a.count("/") == 0 else '/').split("\\\\" if a.count("/") == 0 else '/')[-1]
```

sample code:

```
b = ['a/b/c/','a/b/c','\\a\\b\\c','\\a\\b\\c\\','a\\b\\c','a/b/../../a/b/c/','a/b/../../a/b/c']

for a in b:

    print (a, a.rstrip("\\" if a.count("/") == 0 else '/').split("\\" if a.count("/") == 0 else '/')[-1])
```

Comment: Also, feel free to send me pointers on how to format in this venue.   Took half a dozen tries to get the sample code in place.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, here is the `pathlib` solution for python 3.2+:

```
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

>>> paths = ['a/b/c/', 'a/b/c', '\\a\\b\\c', '\\a\\b\\c\\', 'a\\b\\c', 
...          'a/b/../../a/b/c/', 'a/b/../../a/b/c']

>>> [PureWindowsPath(path).name for path in paths]
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

This works on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

In both Python 2 and 3, using the module [pathlib2](https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/pathlib2):

```
import posixpath  # to generate unix paths
from pathlib2 import PurePath, PureWindowsPath, PurePosixPath

def path2unix(path, nojoin=True, fromwinpath=False):
    """From a path given in any format, converts to posix path format
    fromwinpath=True forces the input path to be recognized as a Windows path (useful on Unix machines to unit test Windows paths)"""
    if not path:
        return path
    if fromwinpath:
        pathparts = list(PureWindowsPath(path).parts)
    else:
        pathparts = list(PurePath(path).parts)
    if nojoin:
        return pathparts
    else:
        return posixpath.join(*pathparts)
```

Usage:

```
In [9]: path2unix('lala/lolo/haha.dat')
Out[9]: ['lala', 'lolo', 'haha.dat']

In [10]: path2unix(r'C:\lala/lolo/haha.dat')
Out[10]: ['C:\\', 'lala', 'lolo', 'haha.dat']

In [11]: path2unix(r'C:\lala/lolo/haha.dat') # works even with malformatted cases mixing both Windows and Linux path separators
Out[11]: ['C:\\', 'lala', 'lolo', 'haha.dat']
```

With your testcase:

```
In [12]: testcase = paths = ['a/b/c/', 'a/b/c', '\\a\\b\\c', '\\a\\b\\c\\', 'a\\b\\c',
    ...: ...     'a/b/../../a/b/c/', 'a/b/../../a/b/c']

In [14]: for t in testcase:
    ...:     print(path2unix(t)[-1])
    ...:
    ...:
c
c
c
c
c
c
c
```

The idea here is to convert all paths into the unified internal representation of `pathlib2`, with different decoders depending on the platform. Fortunately, `pathlib2` includes a generic decoder called `PurePath` that should work on any path. In case this does not work, you can force the recognition of windows path using `fromwinpath=True`. This will split the input string into parts, the last one is the leaf you are looking for, hence the `path2unix(t)[-1]`.

If the argument `nojoin=False`, the path will be joined back, so that the output is simply the input string converted to a Unix format, which can be useful to compare subpaths across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method on Windows and Ubuntu (WSL) and it works as (I) expected only using 'import os':
So basically, replace() put the right path seperator based on your current os platform.

If the path finished by a slash '/', then it's not a file but a directory, so it returns an empty string.

```py
import os

my_fullpath = r"D:\MY_FOLDER\TEST\20201108\20201108_073751.DNG"
os.path.basename(my_fullpath.replace('\\',os.sep))

my_fullpath = r"/MY_FOLDER/TEST/20201108/20201108_073751.DNG"
os.path.basename(my_fullpath.replace('\\',os.sep))

my_fullpath = r"/MY_FOLDER/TEST/20201108/"
os.path.basename(my_fullpath.replace('\\',os.sep))

my_fullpath = r"/MY_FOLDER/TEST/20201108"
os.path.basename(my_fullpath.replace('\\',os.sep))
```

On Windows (Left) and Ubuntu (via WSL, Right):
[image]