# Python: elegant way to split a string in order to pick the last element when the len of string is unknown

Tags: python, performance, path, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python, extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

I have a string as:

```
filename = "C:\\mydata\\yourdata\\Finaldata.txt"
>>> filename
'C:\\mydata\\yourdata\\Finaldata.txt'
```

i wish to split and pick the last element also when i don't know where is the path. I wrote these lines code

```
from os import path
path.splitext(filename)[0].split("\\")[len(path.splitext(filename)[0].split("\\"))-1]
'Finaldata'
```

but i am looking if there is an elegant way to do this.
thanks in advance for any help
Gianni

Comment: To get the last element of a list you can use negative indexes. `my_list[-1]` is the last element, `my_list[-2]` is the one-to-last element etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
os.path.basename(aPath)
```

This will give you just the last component. If you then want to split apart the extension, use:

```
os.path.splitext(aBasename)
```

Using [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) instead of string splitting it more portable because it will figure out the proper separator for you per platform.

If it were *nix/osx, those `\\` would be `/` and you would then have to make case tests. os.path figures it all out for you.

Lastly, `/` is also valid in windows python scripts, for path strings. I recommend just always using them because its easier than escaping a backslash:

```
filename = "C:/mydata/yourdata/Finaldata.txt"
```

Comment: thanks!! and nice post really useful. I can do 
os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
to get 'Finaldata'