# ntpath.basename() alternative?

Tags: python, filepath

I'm trying to use `ntpath.basename()` to take a string like `/Users/user/file_one` and get `file_one`. However, I'm having problems with `ntpath`. It works when I run the script, but after I py2app it, ntpath no longer works. Is there an alternative to ntpath? I'm not sure what special features it has for Windows, but my script is build for OS X, and therefore only uses forward slashes, so I should be fine without the "NT magic" that ntpath offers.

Comment: After `py2app`-ing, can you still access `os.path.basename`?

Comment: Why would you use `ntpath` on a POSIX path?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format

Comment: @DSM that works perfectly, you might want to make that an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.path.split('/Users/user/file_one')[1])
file_one
>>> print(os.path.basename('/Users/user/file_one'))
file_one
```