# Separate file name from path

Tags: python, file

I have a file whose path is like this :
D:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Folder\File1.txt. 
Here **File1.txt** is file name. Now I want to separate this file name from the file path.
If I have,

**path = C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Folder\File1.txt**

then I want to store this name of the file in to **filename**. so output will look like this : **filename=File1.txt**
I am not getting any idea about this. I am new in python..can anybody help me please in python...???

Comment: do you have any code at all? what have you tried?

Comment: I am working on client-server networking in python. I have to send this file name to server. for this I've to separate this file name.so I've wrote complete code for client and server in python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Answer (score 8):

use `os` module

```
import os 
fileName = os.path.basename(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already have pathname, just split it and extract the filename from it

```
path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\Folder\\File1.txt"
temp=path.split('\\')
filename=temp[-1]
print filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want file name without knowing what os is ,

try this ,

```
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.basename("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Folder\File1.txt")
'File1.txt'
>>> ntpath.basename("/etc/apache-perl/httpd.conf")
'httpd.conf'
```