# How to get the latest file name without path in a folder?

Tags: python

```py
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print latest_file
```

This code prints the file path as well, which is not required. I just need the latest file name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate file name from path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235915/separate-file-name-from-path)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Answer (score 0):

Try `os.path.basename(latest_file)`, see [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path):

```py
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(os.path.basename(latest_file))
```

Get's you `foo.bar`

Comment: Great Answer, worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_files = '//x.x.x./y$/Process/Daily_Mismatch_Report/'
```

def get_latest_file(path, *paths):
"""Returns the name of the latest (most recent) file
of the joined path(s)"""
fullpath = os.path.join(path, *paths)
files = glob.glob(fullpath)
if not files:
return None
latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
filename = os.path.split(latest_file)
return filename
p,f= get_latest_file(list_of_files,'*.txt')
print(f)