# Python regex over multiple newlines

Tags: python, regex, newline

I have a string which contains multiple file paths, some of which contain arbitrary newlines within the path, and I want to parse the string using python so that only the filenames and extensions remain.

For example:

```
a/b/c/d/file1.c  
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1/2/3/4/5/foo.c  
dir1/dir2/newlinedir  
/nextlinedir/bar.c
```

should be parsed to give output:

> file1.c
>   foo.c
>   bar.c

I am using the following regular expression (the groups for the filename and extension must be separate for later purposes):

```
path_regex = re.compile(r'.*\/([^\/\.]*)(\.c){0,1}$', re.MULTILINE)
path_regex.sub(r'\g<1>\g<2>', input_string)
```

This will work on strings with single line paths but not paths that contain newlines.
What should I do?

Comment: See this : <<< http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format >>>

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work for a path with a newline within it.

Comment: do `string.replace("\n","")` that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([\s\S]*?\/)(\w+\.c)
```

Try this.See demo.This will work `multiline` too.Use `m` or `multiline` flag.

https://regex101.com/r/rX1tE6/7

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `(?:.*\/)(.+)\.(.+)`

Use \1 to access filename and \2 to access extension

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lY9xB7/1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to have dir1/dir2/newlinedir  removed too, and move bar.c to the previous line. Only the filename and extension must remain, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
>>> s = '''a/b/c/d/file1.c  
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/1/2/3/4/5/foo.c  
dir1/dir2/newlinedir  
/nextlinedir/bar.c'''
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?s).*?([^/]+\.c)', r'\1\n', s))
file1.c
foo.c
bar.c
```

or

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?s).*?([^/]+)(\.[^.\n]+)(?=$|\n)', r'\1\2\n', s))
file1.c  
foo.c  
bar.c
```

Comment: OP said, *the groups for the filename and extension must be separate for later purposes*

Answer (score 0):

This simple regex also works and you can access the filename with extension using \1

```
([^/]*\.\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not what you are asking for, but maybe regex here is not the right tool, since [now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

I think this is what you are searching for:

```
pydoc os.path.basename
```

So try with this:

```
map(os.path.basename, text.split('\n'))
```