# Python regular expression for

Tags: python, regex

What would be the regular expression for such data

```
/home//Desktop/3A5F.py
path/sth/R67G.py
a/b/c/d/t/6UY7.py
```

i would like to get these

```
3A5F.py
R67G.py
6UY7.py
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? (hint: no regular expressions are needed)

Comment: `"/home//Desktop/3A5F.py".split("/")[-1]`

Comment: Maybe a dupe of [*Python, extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/python-extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're parsing paths, in which case you should really be using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) instead of regex:

```
from os.path import basename
basename('/home//Desktop/3A5F.py')
# 3A5F.py
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple `split`, no regex needed:

```
>>> "/home//Desktop/3A5F.py".split("/")[-1]
'3A5F.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can get same result **without regexps**:

```
lines = ['/home//Desktop/3A5F.py', 'path/sth/R67G.py', 'a/b/c/d/t/6UY7.py']

result = [l.split('/')[-1] for l in lines]
print result
# ['3A5F.py', 'R67G.py', '6UY7.py']
```

Answer (score 0):

use : `[^\/]*\.py$`

But this is a bad question. You need to show what you have try. Whe are not here to do your work for you.

Comment: *But this is a bad question.*  - then why answer? (basically, this is a question to everyone answering here).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
pattern = ".*/(.*$)"
mystring = "/home//Desktop/3A5F.py"
re.findall(pattern, mystring)
```

You can also use `os.path.split(mystring)`