# How to remove all characters before the final \

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I have a variable called `dllName` that grabs the name of a dll that has been executed. Sometimes this dll is returned in the format of `"kernel32.dll"` and sometimes as `"C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll"`.

The path can vary, what I am trying to achieve is the stripping of the `"C:\Windows\system32\"`.

EDIT: [*Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

My question is not the same as this question, as os.path.basename and os.path.split do not work in this situation.

For os.path.split the head is empty and the tail contains the whole path?

Comment: No regex required, just use [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried that doesn't work or that you have difficulties with? If you haven't tried any code yourself yet, you could use the search functionality on stackoverflow maybe?

Comment: @Rawing: `os.path.basename` won't work for Windows path on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
path = 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\kernel32.dll'
print path.split('\\')[-1]
#=>  kernel32.dll
```

or

```
import os.path
print os.path.basename(path)
```

or

```
import re

def extract_basename(path):
  """Extracts basename of a given path. Should Work with any OS Path on any OS"""
  basename = re.search(r'[^\\/]+(?=[\\/]?$)', path)
  if basename:
    return basename.group(0)

print extract_basename(path)
```

This last example should work for any OS, any Path.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/PEALFz/1) are some tests.

Comment: Option 1 works, option 2 does not. Thank for your help!

Comment: Option 2 does not work for Windows path on Linux. Option 3 should work for any path on any OS.