# How can I trim strings strings dynamically?

Tags: python

Sample Data :

```
D:\Movies\Iron Man\Iron Man.mp4
D:\Movies\Kung Fu Panda 3\Kung Fu Panda 3.mp4
D:\Movies\SING\SING.mp4
D:\Movies\Split\Split.mp4
D:\Movies\Zootopia\Zootopia.mp4
```

How can I trim these paths just before the backslash while iterating through a `for` loop, so that I can extract the names. i.e.

```
Iron Man.mp4
Kung Fu Panda 3.mp4
SING.mp4
Split.mp4
Zootopia.mp4
```

It will be really helpful of you to help.

Comment: take a look at [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)function

Comment: take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384788/5831538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of [`os.path.basename()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) and [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) as follows:

```
import os

movie_filenames = [
    r"D:\Movies\Iron Man\Iron Man.mp4",
    r"D:\Movies\Kung Fu Panda 3\Kung Fu Panda 3.mp4",
    r"D:\Movies\SING\SING.mp4",
    r"D:\Movies\Split\Split.mp4",
    r"D:\Movies\Zootopia\Zootopia.mp4",
    ]
    
for movie_filename in movie_filenames:
    basename = os.path.basename(movie_filename)
    movie_name = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
    print(movie_name)
```

The first call will extract the filename from the path, and the second call with split out the name from the extension (you only want the name, thus the `[0]`). This would give you:

```
Iron Man
Kung Fu Panda 3
SING
Split
Zootopia
```