# How to remove part of a string from a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following variable:

`input_file = 'gs://tinydancer/test_files/GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.flac'`

I would like to use the `GoogleSheetsandPython_1min` portion of the input_file variable to name a .txt file.
That will be created later in the script.

I would also like to append .txt to the end the file name.

Here is how I am achieving this currently:

`text_file = open("GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.txt", "a")`

By simply hardcoding it in, I want to make this automated. So that once input file was set, you could use this to change the output .txt file name accordingly. I have done some research on this but have not found good way to do this so far.

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `os.path.basename`

```
import os

input_file = 'gs://tinydancer/test_files/GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.flac'
new_file = os.path.basename(input_file).replace("flac", "txt")
text_file = open(new_file, "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string along the `/` and get the last item and then append ".txt" like this:

```
>>> input_file.split('/')[-1] + '.txt'
'GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.flac.txt'
```

In case I misunderstood and you want to replace `.flac` with `.txt`, you can just do another split on `.` and then append the `.txt`.

```
>>> input_file.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] + '.txt'
'GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.txt'
```

Regex solution:

```
import re

>>> re.search('[^/][\\\.A-z0-9]*$', input_file).group()
'GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.flac'
```

Then you can split on the `.` to get rid of the file extension.

Comment: You could use `.rsplit("/", 1)[1]` instead - a bit more efficient.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am looking for in the `text_file` variable, any suggestions on how to remove the front of that `input_file`? This: `gs://tinydancer/test_files/` I was thinking something along the lines of `input_file.remove[?] but I wasn't sure on what index to use since it is "technically" all one word. Or is it?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Isn't that what I just showed you?

Comment: Or you could use regex to get the filename `re.search('[^/][\.A-z0-9]*$', input_file).group()` outputs: `'GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.flac'`

Comment: @EliC strings are immutable

Answer (score 0):

using `os.path`

```
import os

input_file = 'gs://tinydancer/test_files/GoogleSheetsandPython_1min.flac'
input_file = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_file))[0] + '.txt'
```