# Should I Use Regex to Get a File Name?

Tags: python, regex, string, tkinter, filenames

I'm currently working with `tkinter` in Python (beginner), and I'm writing a small applet that requires one of the labels to dynamically change based on what the name of a selected .csv file is, without the '.csv' tag.

I can currently get the filepath to the .csv file using `askopenfilename()`, which returns a string that looks something like `"User/Folder1/.../filename.csv"`. I need some way to extract `"filename"` from this filepath string, and I'm a bit stuck on how to do it. Is this simply a regex problem? Or is there a way to do this using string indices? Which is the "better" way to do it? Any help would be great. Thank you.

EDIT: The reason I was wondering if regex is the right way to do it is because there could be duplicates, e.g. if the user had something like `"User/Folder1/hello/hello.csv"`. That's why I was thinking maybe just use string indices, since the file name I need will always end at [:-4]. Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: First split at '/' to get the last "filename.csv", call it _foo_. Then take _foo[:-4]_ to rid of the suffix.

Comment: Your approach is fine. Using string indices works. Regex is overkill here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
import os
file = open('/some/path/to/a/test.csv')
fname = os.path.splitext(str(file))[0].split('/')[-1]
print(fname)

# test
```

If you get file path and name as string, then:

```
import os
file = "User/Folder1/test/filename.csv"
fname = os.path.splitext(file)[0].split('/')[-1]
print(fname)

# filename
```

**Explanation** on how it works:

Pay attention that command is os.path.split**EXT**, not os.path.split**TEXT** - very common mistake.

The command takes argument of type `string`, so if we use `file = open(...)`, then we need to pass `os.path.splitext` argument of type `string`. Therefore in our first scenario we use:

```
str(file)
```

Now, this command splits complete `file path + name` string into two parts:

```
os.path.splitext(str(file))

# result:
['/some/path/to/a/test','csv']
```

In our case we only need first part, so we take it by specifying list index:

```
os.path.splitext(str(file))[0]

# result: 
'/some/path/to/a/test'
```

Now, since we only need file name and not the whole path, we split it by `/`:

```
os.path.splitext(str(file))[0].split('/')

# result:
['some','path','to','a','test']
```

And out of this we only need one last element, or in other words, first from the end:

```
os.path.splitext(str(file)[0].split('/')[-1]
```

Hope this helps.

Check for more here: [Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)