# Removing /. spaces when printing a filename

Tags: python, printing, filenames, glob, os.path

I'm trying to print out the filename of files in my folder but unfortunately when I print it out it comes out as - Image is ././Image_crop 4.jpg - how do I get rid of the ././ in front of the file? I'm new to python so please help!

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(".", '*.jpg')):
    y = os.path.join(".", filename)
    print "Image is ", y
```

Comment: Change `y = os.path.join(".", filename)` to `y = filename`? And if you want to get rid of both, also change `os.path.join(".", '*.jpg')` to `'*.jpg'`?

Comment: If you just want the actual filename: Have look at [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) - 
But why are you joining the "." in the first place?

Comment: You should just stop to put the `./` in front of the actual glob. You put one in in the first line and one in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
print os.path.basename(filename)
```

It will remove the path and give you the actual filename only. See [Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format) for more info.