# Python : How to call csv files from the directory based on the list of items?

Tags: python

I have a list of items and I want to call only those csv files from the directory whose names are similar to the items in the list. I am doing something like below but its reading all the files from the directory. Please suggest.

```
x_list = [ a,b,c,d]
files in directory = [a.csv, b.csv, c.csv, d.csv, e.csv, f.csv]

for files in os.listdir(dir + 'folder\\'):
    file_name = files[:files.find('.')]
    if file_name in x_list:
        print(file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

From official doc : "The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are returned in arbitrary order."

```py
import glob
dirPath = "/home/.../"
pattern = dirPath + '*.csv'

for file_path in glob.glob(pattern):
    print(file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. What could be the 'file_name' based on post ?

Comment: You could use split command applied to file_path (last elmt in list is file.csv) :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for which you'll need the re module.

```
import re
print(*(file for file in os.listdir() if re.match(r".*\.csv", file) and file[:-4] in x), sep='\n')
```

You can also use the filter function:

```
print(*filter(lambda file:  re.match(r".*\.csv", file) and file[:-4] in x, os.listdir(), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just open the CSVs on your list: This is what you could do:

```py
# a b c d are names of CSVs without .csv extension
my_csvs_names =  'a b c d'.split()
my_csvs_folder = 'c/path/to/my_folder'

for csv_name in my_csvs_names:
    file_name = f'{my_csvs_folder}/{csv_name}.csv'
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f_in:
            for line in f_in:
                # do something with it
                print(line)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'{file_name} does not exist')
```

In doing something, you can append values to a variable or whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi..Is 'my_csvs_names ' a list ? Because I have a list of names.

Comment: Yes! `'a b c'.split() == ['a', 'b', 'c']`