# How take name from file and add to path

Tags: python, selenium, path, driver

i wrote in python small code, how to take in sequence line from nicknames.txt and add to webpath like first line is "joe" -> [www.example.com/joe](http://www.example.com/joe)

```
import requests,os
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= r'geckodriver.exe')

    class Checker:
      def Nicknames():
          text = open('nicknames.txt').read()
    
      def __init__(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
          self.driver.get("https://pl.namemc.com/" + 'text')
          sleep(3)
    
    
          name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/h1")
          cape = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]")
          print('name', " | ", 'cape')
    
    Checker()
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Pls men its late in night and my mind is not working good XD give answer pls

Comment: what exactly are you asking?  how to take name from what fhile and add to what path?  Incidentally..  I would believe you're missing ```return text``` in ```def Nicknames():```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format?rq=1) to find the file name of your retried file  (I dont know your os or what you mean by 'text'), and once you have that you can concatenate it with your path.