# How to remove an unknown string part in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a FileDialogue Object in Tkinter that gets the location of a file from the User's Computer.

The output is not always the same as the directory may vary.

For E.G. = `Filename = C:/MusicDirectory/Music.mp3`, or it can be something else too, like `D:/Some/Directory/IDontKnowWhatToTypeAnyMore/Music.mp3`

My main objective is to remove the "`C:/MusicDirectory/`" and the unwanted Directory from the string, but the string does not remain the same. It can be some other folder too.

Can someone help me in this situation?

Comment: So you want to just get the filename?

Comment: Yes, @Moosefeather, I just want to get the filename. Like, the filename is `something.mp3` and I just want to get that name and not the directory like `C:/`

Comment: Lots of good discussion about this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

```
os.path.basename('C:/MusicDirectory/Music.mp3') # 'Music.mp3'

os.path.basename('D:/Some/Directory/IDontKnowWhatToTypeAnyMore/Music.mp3') # 'Music.mp3'
```

Comment: Thank You M8, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: @xpDev glad I could help, you can also check out the [`pathlib.PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) object which could be convenient if you're doing other operations on the path. (In this case if you'd use [`PurePath.name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name))

Comment: Thanks @MooseFeather for your effort.