# How to save an ammended image filename while maintaining an original file extention

Tags: python, image, save, filenames

I have a task of watermarking the image using python pillow. The function is supposed to take in two parameters: 1. Name of an image file and 2.Message - This is text that should be watermarked onto the image

The function should save the watermarked image with the name of the original file with a “_zz” appended to the of the name before the period.

I used the 'classic" python pillow approach:

```
def watermark (name, message):
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
    im = Image.open(name)
    width, height = im.size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    text = message
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
    textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text, font)
    margin = 10
    x = width - textwidth - margin
    y = height - textheight - margin
    draw.text((x, y), text, font=font)

    im.show()
    im.save(name+'_zz') # incorrect of course
```

I can't figure out how to save the file with '_zz" amended to file name only and not to the extension.
I am new to Python, please be patient with me...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format

Answer (score 0):

Cool! I am answering my own question... Very simple:
`

```
    e=name.split(".")[-1]
    n=name.split(".")[0]
    wm_name=(n+'_zz'+'.'+e)

    im.save(zz_name)
```

`