# Replace part of the list element

Tags: python

I have a list variable which has elemnts like below:
`['Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131121.csv', 'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131150.csv', 'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131160.csv', 'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131169.csv', 'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131189.csv']`

This is file name with file path in it.
Want to build a list with only file name, how can i do that?
Output should be:

`['bounce-20211109-131121.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131150.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131160.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131169.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131189.csv']` 
ie strip out string 'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `os.path.basename` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)) and get the last segment. Then you just need to trim the part you don't want.

```
import os
data = [
    'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131121.csv', 
    'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131150.csv',
    'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131160.csv',
    'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131169.csv',
    'Cordial/contactactivity/export/bounce/0-ContactActivity-bounce-20211109-131189.csv'
]
data = [os.path.basename(i).replace('0-ContactActivity-', '') for i in data]
```

resulting in:

```
>>> data
['bounce-20211109-131121.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131150.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131160.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131169.csv', 'bounce-20211109-131189.csv']
```

Comment: Why not just use [`basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)? *"Return the base name of pathname path. __This is the second element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split()__"*

Comment: It works, Thank you!

Comment: Can also use [`removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) (Python >= 3.9) instead of `replace`

Comment: @Tomerikoo good point.