# Python: How can I remove multiple occurrences of "\\" from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

```
string = "C:\\folder\\important\\week1.xlsx"
```

I need to extract the file name alone, "week1.xlsx" from this string.
But for some reason, it doesn't work.

Comment: Those are already single backslashes. They are just escaped.

Comment: I a string like this (not raw) a double backslash represents a single backslash. You should consider using raw strings (`r'...'`) when working with backslashes.

Comment: `"C:\\folder\\important\\week1.xlsx".split('\\')[-1]` ... ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `basename`:

```
import os
str(os.path.basename("C:\\folder\\important\\week1.xlsx"))

=> 'week1.xlsx'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
filename = string[string.rfind('\\')+1:]
```

Here's [more info on rfind()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-rfind-method/).

Comment: I'd love to understand why has this been downvoted. It solves the OP's question.