# Isolating file names from paths in python

Tags: python, filenames, filepath

I am trying to isolate file names from paths imported using "filedialog.askopenfilenames". I am doing that so I can use them later in plots.

Let us say for example that I imported three excel files that have the following names:
"sample_excel_1","sample_excel_2.xlsx","sample_excel_3.xlsx"

The output in my case is the full paths of the files( i.e.,  ('//tudelft.net/staff-homes/K/mkhadijeh/Desktop/Python/sample_excel_1.xlsx', '//tudelft.net/staff-homes/K/mkhadijeh/Desktop/Python/sample_excel_2.xlsx', '//tudelft.net/staff-homes/K/mkhadijeh/Desktop/Python/sample_excel_3.xlsx') )

I would like the outputs to be instead **("sample_excel_1","sample_excel_2.xlsx","sample_excel_3.xlsx")**

Any help!

The code is below:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np


filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="c:/", title="Selecte a file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files","*.*")))

a = filename
print(a)
```

I want a to be a list so I can easily access it later (i.e.,  ["sample_excel_1","sample_excel_2.xlsx","sample_excel_3.xlsx"]
)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract file name from path, no matter what the os/path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new, please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the file name as the full path, and you want the names for later (future) process you could do one of the following:

1- loop through the list you have now and use os.path.basename to get the files name:

```
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np


filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="c:/", title="Selecte a file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files","*.*")))

a = filename
a = [os.path.basename(path) for path in a]
print(a)
```

2- or using split lib, by splitting on '\' and get the last element in the generated list

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="c:/", title="Selecte a file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files","*.*")))

a = filename
a = [path.split('\')[-1] for path in a]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Then using the `pathlib` library is recommended for cross platform compatibility instead of `os`:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
from pathlib import PurePath

a = []

filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="c:/", title="Selecte a file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"),("All files","*.*")))

for f in filename:
    a.append(PurePath(filename).name)
print(a)
```

**EDIT:** I didn't see the multiple output that filename could generate. Fixed it.