# When I write .txt files to zip file (using the paths of the .txt files), it creates folders within the zip file by default?

Tags: python, file, text, zip

So I have a list that contains paths to two text files:

```
file_paths = ['/tmp/bmex-2023-07-28-w0hrsh25/MFII_MC_TICK_H_20230703.TXT', '/tmp/bmex-2023-07-28-w0hrsh25/MFII_MC_TICK_AE_20230703.TXT']
```

I want to write these two text files into a zip file, I do:

```
with ZipFile(str(new_file), 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) as merged_archive:
    for file in file_paths:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            merged_archive.writestr(file, f.read())
```

I've omitted some details about `new_file`, it's quite complex but I can include it if it is relavant. I don't think it is, the only relavant part is that `merged_archive` is the zip file in question.

When I open the zip file I expect the two text files, but when I do the above and open the zip file after, I get:

```
zip_file/
├── tmp/
    ├── embedded/
        ├── bmex-equities3-2023-07-28-n3matya5
             └── two_text_files_are_here
```

I can understand why it is creating these directories, clearly becuase I am feeding it file paths instead of the file names.

But I can't figure out a solution, becuase if I feed it the file names only, it will return something like:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MFII_MC_TICK_H_20230703.TXT'
```

Which I totally understand!

Any ideas?

Comment: **Edit2:** failed to properly read, [see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format). -- You put the whole path into `writestr`, which creates it inside the ZIP. Extract just the filename and use that. **Edit:** [shutil.make_archive](https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) may also interest you when zipping all files in a folder.

Comment: Thanks @ivvija, as mentioned towards the bottom of the question, if I just put the filename, I run into a `FileNotFoundError` - any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: OK ignore my comment - I just clicked into your link!