# Remove First 5 directories in a file path column from data frame

Tags: python

My dataframe looks like

```
print df_function
    
   address              function        file_name  
 
   0xffffffff87954120  load_buf   /a/b/c/d/e/f/...        
   0xffffffff87954121  load_buf   /a/b/c/d/e/f/...     
   ....
   ....
```

Column "file_name" isn't displaying complete file path and it should like something like

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f/file1.c
/a/b/c/d/e/f/file2.c
```

I dont need the first 5 directories in the filename column and require file path only after skiping the first 5 directories

**Desired Output:**

```
   address              function        file_name  
 
   0xffffffff87954120  load_buf    f/file1.c       
   0xffffffff87954121  load_buf    f/file2.c     
   ....
   ....
```

I tried

```
file_paths = df_function["file_name"].str.split("/")
file_paths = [x[5:] for x in file_paths]
new_file_paths = "".join(file_paths)
df_function["file_name"] = new_file_paths
```

I get error:

```
new_file_paths = "".join(file_paths)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: I think this question could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384737/extract-file-name-from-path-no-matter-what-the-os-path-format. There's a few different ways you can extract the filename from a filepath that are outlined here

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.This link provides support to get only basenames. I am interested in file path completely after stripping the first 5 file path directories.

Comment: Are all 5th directories on the same path? If yes you can easily use `str.replace`.

Comment: Yes, all the 5 directories are from the same path..How can I replace a complete column stripping first 5 dir paths ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You were quite close with your attempt. You get the error message because the `join()` method requires a list of strings, and not a list of lists like you had. Also when you're slicing the `str.split()` results, you need to request the first 6 elements instead of the first 5. This is because the first element contains what is before the very first file path slash: an empty string. Here is working code based on your attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["0xffffffff87954120", "load_buf", "/a/b/c/d/e/f/file1.c"],    
    ["0xffffffff87954121", "load_buf", "/a/b/c/d/e/f/file2.c"],
]
col_names = ["address", "function", "file_name"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)

file_paths = df["file_name"].str.split("/")
new_file_paths = ["/".join(x[6:]) for x in file_paths]
df["file_name"] = new_file_paths

print(df)
```

which prints the following:

```
              address  function  file_name
0  0xffffffff87954120  load_buf  f/file1.c
1  0xffffffff87954121  load_buf  f/file2.c
```

### Solution 2

You can also keep the data inside the dataframe at all times like so:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["0xffffffff87954120", "load_buf", "/a/b/c/d/e/f/file1.c"],    
    ["0xffffffff87954121", "load_buf", "/a/b/c/d/e/f/file2.c"],
]
col_names = ["address", "function", "file_name"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)

df["file_name"] = (
    df["file_name"]
    .str.split("/")
    .map(lambda x: x[6:])
    .str.join("/")
)

print(df)
```

which prints the following:

```
              address  function  file_name
0  0xffffffff87954120  load_buf  f/file1.c
1  0xffffffff87954121  load_buf  f/file2.c
```

### Solution 3

Alternatively you can use pandas' [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to capture only the part of the file path that you want with a regular expression:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["0xffffffff87954120", "load_buf", "/a/b/c/d/e/f/file1.c"],    
    ["0xffffffff87954121", "load_buf", "/a/b/c/d/e/f/file2.c"],
]
col_names = ["address", "function", "file_name"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)

df["file_name"] = df["file_name"].str.extract(r"(?:/[\w\.-]+){5}/(.+)")

print(df)
```

which prints the following:

```
              address  function  file_name
0  0xffffffff87954120  load_buf  f/file1.c
1  0xffffffff87954121  load_buf  f/file2.c
```

For a detailed break-down of the regular expression, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/ctuDr2/1).

Answer (score -1):

To remove first 5 directories from your paths you can use split from regex library to separate the directories and join from os.path to join the directories after slicing with [6:]

```
>>> from os.path import join
>>> from re import split
>>> path = '/a/b/c/d/e/f/file.c'
>>> new_path = join(*split("/", path)[6:])
>>> new_path
'f\\file.c'
>>> paths
['/a/b/c/d/e/f/file1.c', '/a/b/c/d/e/f/file2.c', '/a/b/c/d/e/f/file3.c']
>>> new_paths = [join(*split("/", path)[6:]) for path in paths]
>>> new_paths
['f\\file1.c', 'f\\file2.c', 'f\\file3.c']
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work if I have more directories in the file path after first 5 directories

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.This link provides support to get only basenames. I am interested in file path completely after stripping the first 5 file path directories. I need to display f/file1.c , g/file2.c

Comment: Please review my edit, thanks.