# Get folder from path python

Tags: python, path

i have this path

```
c:\JAVA\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse\configuration\
```

i want to get back the last folder "configuration"
or on

```
c:\JAVA\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse\configuration\S\D\CV\S\D\D\AAAAA
```

get "AAAAA"

i don't found this function on os.path
thanks

Comment: If you're careful to ensure there are no trailing slashes, [os.path.basename()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) does what you're after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only the last part of a path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925096/how-to-get-only-the-last-part-of-a-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know you have a separator character `sep`, this should accomplish what you ask:

```
path.split(sep)[-1]
```

Where `path` is the `str` containing your path.

If you don't know what the separator is you can call

```
os.path.sep
```

Comment: i want build in function

Comment: @JONI6543: split *is* a built-in function for strings?

Comment: built in like os.path.getfolder()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.split` to split according to path separator:

```
os.path.split(path)[-1]
```

Comment: i want build in function

Comment: os.path.split(path)[-1]

Answer (score 0):

please check the code

```
import os


def getFolderName(str):
    if(str.endswith("\\")):
        str = str[0:-2]
    return os.path.split(str)[-1]

print(getFolderName(r'c:\JAVA\eclipse\java-neon\eclipse\configuration\S\D\CV\S\D\D\AAAAA'))
```

Comment: no good
if the path like c:\a\b\
that not return b(because the \ is in the end)

Comment: add `if(str.endswith("\\")):
        str = str[0:-2]` check.

Answer (score 0):

if you're wanting to explore your paths try something like this

```
def explore(path):
    finalpaths = []
    for paths in os.listdir(path):
        nextpath = path + '/' + paths
        if os.path.isdir(nextpath):
            finalpaths.extend(explore(nextpath))
        else:
            finalpaths.append(path)
    return finalpaths
```

then if you run

```
set(explore(path)
```

you'll get a list of all folders that can be in that directory (the lowest folder down you can get)

this works for unix, you might need to change it to \ rather than / for windows