# get child filename from path in python without using split

Tags: python

Suppose I have a path like `C:\\exportDir\\testing\\content\\catalog\\root\\shared\\First\\First_content\\Report1`

How can I retreive the child filename in my case `Report1` without using split by `\\`

Comment: This is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925096/how-to-get-only-the-last-part-of-a-path-in-python

Comment: use  os.listdir(folder_name), will get a list of file names from path

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use `os.path.split()`

Example:

```
import os 
  
# path 
path = '/home/User/Desktop/file.txt'
  
# Split the path in  
# head and tail pair 
head_tail = os.path.split(path) 
  
# print head and tail 
# of the specified path 
print("Head of '% s:'" % path, head_tail[0]) 
print("Tail of '% s:'" % path, head_tail[1], "\n")
```

Comment: Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is much more sympathetic than `os.path` and is as easy as doing `pathlib.Path(path).name`